# Export camera gallery in Watchdogs 2

Tags: ps4, watch-dogs-2

In Watchdogs 2 you can take pictures on the game’s phone and save them to a gallery.

Is is possible to export these to the console itself so they can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only  way I've worked out how to do this, which would work for any game would be to load up the picture you want to save to your PS4 in full screen (remove any HUDs if possible) and then hit share and save a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Watch Dogs 2 does not allows you to store the pictures taken from your phone to the PS4 Gallery.